# how to show string data in html table on success call of ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I got my data in sucess alert like:
`Kiran PaswanKiranpaswan@sbpbic.com8800134507`
there is no key or id.

It returns only value or string. Now I want this data in a table below the headers name email phone, but I have no idea how to do this. Here is my code of the ajax call:

```
     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/assessment/omr-evaluation/post-omr-skill-based-career-test.aspx',
            data: { row: data },
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = new Array();
                var names = data
                 arr = names.split('^');
                $('#candy').html(arr);
                 alert(arr);
                  },
```

Comment: What is the response you are getting? Please post it also

Comment: Table should be attached in the question with actual response of ajax. Seems you have returned a string but returning a json would be better choice.

Comment: How you split a plain string?

Comment: i split the string because there are some unwanted ^ are coming hemal

Comment: Noupphal i show  my response in my que

Comment: You can use 'libraries' to do this automatically, like jsRender: https://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/goodby-jquery-templates-hello-jsrender

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
var userTable = $('#user_table_id');
if(userTable  == null || userTable.length == 0  ){
    var table_html = "<table id='user_table_id'>";
    table_html+= "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Email</td><td>Phone</td></tr>";

    table_html+= "</table>";
    $('#candy').html(table_html);
}
userTable = $('#user_table_id');
var newLine = $("<tr><td>"+arr[0]+"</td><td>"+arr[1]+"</td><td>"+arr[2]+"</td></tr>"); 
userTable.append(newLine );
```

The idea is to create a table structure **if it doesn't exist yet**. And then add a row to that table

Comment: yeah its working but i should have to try this code in each loop so that i can show all data in html . because with your code it show only last data which is shown in table

Comment: I made a modification to my solution, please check it

Comment: ikken your previous code is workine fine but it does not.

Comment: function processFiles() {
              d3.csv(("/assessment/omr-evaluation/uploaded-csv/" + $('#Label2').text()), function (data) {
                     $.each(data, function (i) {
                    //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data[i]);
                    var result = '';
                    result = processEachRow(JSON.stringify(data[i]));
                    //alert(i + result);
                });
                // console.log(JSON.stringify(data[i]));

            })
                return false;
        }

Comment: above is my another function to process this data

Comment: I forgot the '#' selector of jQuery in my last update, now, it must be working

Comment: if statement is not working and each data are coming with some delay thansks ikken

Comment: Again, I updated the new table id to be `id='user_table_id'`. I tested it. I hope it can help